# Pulling a value from request.get

Tags: node.js

So I want to pull a value from the request.get in node.js from a web api. I can work with the data within the request.get funtion but I want to pull it out into a variable and that doesn't seem to be working.

```
var Request = require("request");
var variable;

variable = Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    var object = JSON.parse(body);
    var value = object[1];

    return value;
});
```

Any advice?

Comment: I guess you can simply use `variable = value;` inside the function instead of returning it to variable from request response..

Comment: You simply can't do that. The value does not exist now. It exists in the future. You can only access it if you run code after that point in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of an asynchronous call, you should use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You could easily wrap your call inside a `Promise` :

```
var Request = require("request");
var variable;

function getAsyncValue() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            var object = JSON.parse(body);
            var value = object[1];
            resolve(value);
       });
    });
}
```

Then you can consume your asynchronous call and extract the result as the following :

```
getAsyncValue().then((res) => {
    variable = res;
    return variable
}).then((v) => {
    // Do your treatment with variable here ...
}).catch((err) => {
    // Handle your error case ...
});
```

You could also use [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) like below :

```
variable = await getAsyncValue().catch(err => console.log(err));
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: How could I get the value out of the asynchronous call tho?

Comment: variable = await getAsyncValue().catch(err => console.log(err));
console.log(variable);

this part doesn't work

Comment: I am not sure to understand the meaning of "get the value out". However if you do not want to have your result inside a block of code you should probably go with the await syntax (the second example).

Comment: When I use it it gives me an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
and it's pointing to this variable = await getAsyncValue().catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: looks like getAsyncValue is not a correct identifier

Comment: Because you need to wrap your calls with the await identifier inside an async function. Here is a little example : https://jsfiddle.net/bo3ayr6L/

Comment: Is it in any way possible to pull that value from all funtions and just have it as it is? I have a ton of funtions that will be called and this will be a mess otherwise

Comment: I don't know your context but there is nothing wrong about calling functions

Comment: Well there is something extremely wrong with having a function that has 50 functions and each one has a subfunction... Either I do that or I get Promise { <pending> }

Comment: That's why I'd like to return the value when the promise is done to the outer variable, but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper format. You need to install express for this though

```
const express==require('express')
const request=require('request')
const app=express()

app.use(express.json());

request(url,(error,response,body)=>{
  if(error) return console.dir(error);
  const obj=req.body
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign `variable` the return of the `function` `Request.get`, intending to assign the return value of the callback. However, the callback is a different `function`. You can do this:

```
var Request = require("request");
var variable;

Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    var object = JSON.parse(body);
    var variable = object[1];

});
```

This will make sure that your `variable` holds the right value. But still, if you do this:

```
Request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    var object = JSON.parse(body);
    var variable = object[1];
    console.log(variable);
});
console.log(variable);
```

You will see that the first output is `undefined` and then, when the request has finished, the output will be the correct value. The problem is that the code after the `Request.get` call runs **before** the request is finished. You could make your request synchronous and then the system will wait for the request to finish, but that's an anti pattern. You need to handle the request response inside the callback. This will seem to be counter-intuitive at first, but once you get used to it, you will have no problems with it.